# Reading characters from a text file in c and storing in 2d array problems

Tags: c, arrays, file, matrix, multidimensional-array

The code below is given 3 arguments in the command line, the text file, the # of rows in the matrix and the # of columns in the matrix. The file I pass in has 10 rows and 12 columns. If I pass 10(for rows) and 12(for columns) in the command line, for some reason it outputs up until the 8th index row and 7th index column. If i pass 11 and 13 it will output the full matrix plus the @ symbol at the end.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    FILE *f;
    int i = 0,j = 0;

    if(argc != 4)
    {
        printf("You did not enter a file name and/or rows/columns.");
    }
    else
    {
        int rows = atoi(argv[2])  ;
        int columns = atoi(argv[3]) ;
        char matrix[rows][columns];

        f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if(f == NULL)
        {
            printf("Invalid File");
        }
        else
        {
            for(i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++)
            {
                for(j = 0 ; j < columns ; j++)
                {
                    fscanf(f,"%c",&matrix[i][j]);               
                    printf("%c", matrix[i][j]);
                }       
            }
        }

        fclose(f);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fscanf(f,"%c",&matrix[i][j]);` --> `fscanf(f," %c",&matrix[i][j]);` ? Show example of file.

Comment: Yes that worked, thank you so much. Out of curiosity, how does this make the difference?

Comment: Skip the previous white-spaces (newline).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify how your file is structured, so I will just assume that you're accidentally reading in any present blank characters (such as space, newline, tab etc).

Use `" %c"` for `fscanf` instead. Notice the extra space before `'%'`, that is important. It tells `fscanf` to ignore any white-space characters.